# Jenkins Maven job unable to access plugins for deployment from repositories

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am new to Jenkins. As part of POC i tried to deploy a basic SOA project from command line "mvn pre-integration-test", it was successfully deployed to localhost weblogic server. However, when tried Jenkin's job polling svn code, its failing repeatedly with following error msg:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testAppSairu
Updating protocol://xxx/svn/testAppSairu/branches/testAppSairu at revision '2015-10-19T18:08:19.290 +0530'
At revision 2
no change for protocol://xxx/svn/testAppSairu/branches/testAppSairu since the previous build
Setting environment Jenkins.Repository = protocol://localhost:8088/repository/dev
Parsing POMs
Setting environment Jenkins.Repository = protocol://localhost:8088/repository/dev
Setting environment Jenkins.Repository = protocol://localhost:8088/repository/dev
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer com.oracle.soa:sar-common:pom:12.1.3-0-0 from protocol://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle.soa:sar-common:pom:12.1.3-0-0 from/to central (protocol://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to protocol://repo.maven.apache.org refused and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 21, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)

Note: I used maven sync plugin to install and push weblogic home into local repository and also Archiva managed repository. While running mvn compile/pre-integration-test i am able to deploy it successfully but failing here since its unable to access plugins.
```

**.m2 settings.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" 
                              xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>  
  <offline>false</offline>
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>            
            </pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
                    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                        <id>dev</id>
                        <name>Dev</name>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                        </snapshots>
                        <url>http://localhost:8088/repository/dev</url>
                        <layout>default</layout>                    
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>       
           <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                          <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>dev-group</id>
                    <name>Dev Group</name>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <url>http://localhost:8088/repository/dev-group</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>       
                <repository>
                    <id>dev</id>
                    <name>Dev</name>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <url>http://localhost:8088/repository/dev</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>           
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>Archiva Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                    <url>http://localhost:8088/repository/snapshots</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>     
    </profiles> 
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>dev-mirror</id>
            <name>All Else</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8088/repository/dev-group</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
            <username>OTN username</username>
            <password>OTN password</password>
            <configuration>
              <basicAuthScope>
                <host>ANY</host>
                <port>ANY</port>
                <realm>OAM 11g</realm>
              </basicAuthScope>
              <httpConfiguration>
                <all>
                  <params>
                    <property>
                      <name>http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects</name>
                      <value>%b,true</value>
                    </property>
                  </params>
                </all>
              </httpConfiguration>
            </configuration>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>dev</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>       
        <server>
            <id>dev-group</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>    
        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin123</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <activeProfiles>                
        <activeProfile>defualt</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

As suggested in `docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN.pdf`, i have downloaded wagon-http-2.8-shaded.jar and placed under`apache-maven-3.3.3\lib\ext` folder. Updated repository, server details etc in `settings.xml`. But still issue is not resolved.

My intention is to deploy a simgle SOA 12c project using Jenkin's maven job part of Continuous Integration flow. Please suggest if i am missing anything here. I am rookie on this so any help will save my day. Thanks!

Comment: Improve code formatting